# Place link label in the middle of a link in JoinJS

Tags: javascript, html, jointjs

For some reason, when I'm creating a link, in the function `updateLabelPositions` of  `joint.dia.LinkView`, I get `NaN` when the following line is executed:
`var connectionLength = connectionElement.getTotalLength();`

This causes the code to fail later on when calculating the label position.
I'm using *joint.clean.js v0.9.0* + *Backbone 1.0.0*.
This issue occurs only in Firefox 30.0, while in Chrome Version 35.0.xxx... and IE10 it's all fine.

Here is my link creation code:

```js
var link = new joint.dia.Link({
                source: { id: sourceNodeLabel },
                target: { id: targetNodeLabel },
                smooth: true
            });

link.label(0, { position: .5, attrs: {text: { text: 'label', 'font-size': 14, 'font-family': 'san-serif' }}});
```

This code is taken from JoinJS demos: http://www.jointjs.com/demos/links
(link no.6  in their sample)

**EDIT:**

During investigation, I've found out that Mozilla has bug where the function `getTotalLength` of `SVGPathElement` returns `NaN`. Is anyone familiar with this issue maybe?
check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xyk3R/

please let me know if there's any further information is needed.

Cheers!